# Generating basic Nagios configuration with Puppet in the wrong side

Tags: puppet, nagios, puppetdb

I have a little problem when I try to integrate Puppet with Nagios.

This is my configuration (I know, it's so simple but it's my first try)

**/etc/puppet/modules/nagios/manifests/init.pp**

```
class nagios::server {
  package { ["nagios"]:
    ensure => installed,
  }
  service { nagios:
    ensure  => running,
    enable  => true,
  }
  file { 'resource-d':
    path   => '/etc/nagios/objects',
    ensure => directory,
    owner  => 'nagios',
  }
  # Collect the nagios_host resources
  Nagios_host <<||>> {
    require => File[resource-d],
    notify  => [Service[nagios]],
  }
}
```

**/etc/puppet/modules/nagios/manifests/export.pp**

```
class nagios::export {
  @@nagios_host { $::fqdn:
    address       => $::ipaddress,
    check_command => 'check-host-alive!3000.0,80%!5000.0,100%!10',
    hostgroups    => 'all-servers',
    target        => "/etc/nagios/objects/host_${::fqdn}.cfg"
  }
}
```

**/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp**

```
node 'server-1'
{
        include nagios::server
        include nagios::export
}
```

All this stuff is working but the cfgs with Nagios configuration are created in the remote node "server-1" instead of Nagios server (Nagios and Puppet are running in the same server) and I cannot get this configuration from server-1 to be shown in Nagios server. 
Do you have any idea of what is happening?.

Regards

Comment: Is server-1 not the nagios/puppet server? I am confused.  You are doing `include nagios::server` on your `server-1` node, so what do you expect?  Include that on the nagios server node.

Comment: Hi Zoredache. server-1 is the remote server, the server to be monitored by Nagios.
The configuration in /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp file is stored in Nagios-Puppet server. Do I need to put this config in the remote server too?

Comment: on the server that you need to monitor you need "include nagios::export" and on the nagios server "include nagios::server"

Answer (score 0):

Resources need to be exported on the server being monitored and collected on the server running Nagios.  You say that "server-1" is the server being monitored and that you're running Nagios and Puppet on the same server, so I'll assume that second, monitoring server is named "puppet".  Consequently, your Puppet `site.pp` should look like this:

```
node 'puppet' {
    include nagios::server
}
node 'server-1' {
    include nagios::export
}
```